# Is there a way in kubernetes to wait on daemonset ready

Tags: kubernetes

I'm not sure if there is a ready condition in DaemonSet. By that, I mean all pods owned by that DaemonSet are ready.

I'm aware of `kubectl wait`, but it seems can not check the readiness of DaemonSet.

Comment: https://github.com/uswitch/nidhogg is one way to do this

Answer (score 7):

Simpler method from https://starkandwayne.com/blog/silly-kubectl-trick-5-waiting-for-things-to-finish-up-2/ ->

```
kubectl rollout status daemonset \
  rke2-ingress-nginx-controller \
  -n kube-system \
  --timeout 60s
```

Comment: This is the right answer. If the daemonset fails to start, this will report it and exit with a failure return code.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to get pods from your DaemonSet by using following command:

```
kubectl get pods -l <daemonset-selector-key>=<daemonset-selector-value>
```

And then check status of those pods in loop looking if they are ready.

Comment: Yes, this is straightforward, but I'm wondering is it possible for some pods not being created. For example, if ds are about to create 100 pods, and only created 10 ready pods, but 90 pods still in the process of creation. So I'm wondering if check pod is not the right solution.

Comment: But those pods will be in pending state so you can check that. Pods =/= containers

Comment: AFAIK, pending state is for pod created but not scheduled, I know this would work if the pods are in pending. But what I meant is some pods even didn't being created.

Comment: So maybe another check if number of pods is equal to number of nodes? It can be easily done by `kubectl get nodes`

Comment: Well, but some nodes may have taint or ds choose not to run in some nodes. So, I was wondering if k8s provide such mechanism like defining ds readiness.

Comment: The reason why DaemonSet is like this is because when you have a node down (and a pod with it) the DaemonSet is still fully functional. It still has a pod on each living node. So the answer given here is correct, and it feels like what you (OP) are trying to achieve may not even exist. The point is: it's not that easy to define what exactly means "ready" for DaemonSet. Depending on how you define it you write a script that gives you that. A reasonable option is given in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
function wait-for-daemonset(){
    retries=10
    while [[ $retries -ge 0 ]];do
        sleep 3
        ready=$(kubectl -n $1 get daemonset $2 -o jsonpath="{.status.numberReady}")
        required=$(kubectl -n $1 get daemonset $2 -o jsonpath="{.status.desiredNumberScheduled}")
        if [[ $ready -eq $required ]];then
            #echo "Succeeded"
            break
        fi
        ((retries--))
    done
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's largely unnecessary to run a while loop when you can use `kubectl rollout status daemonset <DS_NAME>` to check the status and report failures or block CI pipelines.